# Can we generate mysql database in perl without connecting to server?

Tags: mysql, perl, tcl

Recently i came across a tool written in tcl which generates a mysql database without connecting to a server. It uses some c libraries, can this be done in perl? Sorry if this is too basic question. This is completely new to me, couldnt find much information.

EDIT:

By "generates a mysql database" i mean it generates a directory with mysql tables. I can create a soft link to that directory in mysql and query data from that

Comment: What do you mean by "generates a mysql database?"  Do you mean a SQL database that resides in memory that you can query, etc.?  If so, you can use SQLite.

Comment: Short of having something that does the job of a MySQL server built in that writes to the directories MySQL looks for databases in and then restarts the server when its done (which would be insane) — no. I doubt that the (unspecified) tool you've found actually does that either.

Comment: It generates a directory with mysql tables. I can create a soft link to that directory in mysql and query data from that

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an SQL file maually that builds up a database when imported into a mysql database. I would advise against manyually creating binary tables and copying them under mysql's `data` folder.

On the other hand if you want to use SQL databases locally, without having to run a separate server process try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Can you please explain why you are against to creating binary tables

Comment: I don't think MySQL was build that way or the file format was designed for many processes to work on the same files simultaneously. And if you are just using it for reading data then a one-time import from SQL is really a safer solution. This is the best answer I can give to that question.